# Generating Script's Help String in IPython

Tags: python, string, ipython, documentation

Suppose mycode.py has the following generalized structure:

```
import bla
import bla


def function:
    bla bla


description="""My
multi-line description 
of the
code
"""


import bla
more code here
```

What command in IPython would print the help string given in "description =" ?

All relevant questions on here seem to suggest it would be mycode.**doc** , but that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Doc-strings are strings that are the first thing defined in a module, function or class and are not assigned to a variable/name

my_module.py:

```
"""
This is the module doc-string
"""

def foo():
    """
    This is the function doc-string
    """
    pass
```

Then you can access the doc-string via the `__doc__` attribute

```
import my_module
print(my_module.__doc__)  # This prints "This is the module doc-string"
print(my_module.foo.__doc__)  # This prints "This is the function doc-string"
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding to [@Iain Shelvington's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57734667/10157759) about where to put doc strings, in an interactive environment one can often use the [`help`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) function to access it (note that this function not only works for modules, classes, and functions but also for other things such as keyword strings).

```
help(object)
```

Moreover, in IPython there is a [magic command](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) `%pinfo <object>` for retrieving an object's information including the docstring. Another shorter alias that is very often used is `<object>?`. So if the code is in `my_module.py`, after it is imported, one can access its information using `my_module?`.